# How do I update the password?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, passwords, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on a web app and I want a user to be able to reset their password but I'm failing to do so how can I do it?

I also tried

```
email = request.form.get('email')
new_password = request.form.get('password')

user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
If user :
user.password = new_password. #The new_password
```

Comment: you should provide an example of how a pdf looks like when it is correct and not correct

Comment: @maddes8cht not sure how pdfs are relevant here?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include your actual code - the code as it is is not valid - and an explanation of what is going wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think below should work for your requirements

Here you are getting the `user` by filtering ,you can also get the current logged in user as that will be the one you'll updating password for, and you can update password using below snippet

```
from flask import Flask, session

#current user using
flask_login.current_user 

#or get the user_id just like below
user_id = session["user_id"]

user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
user.modify(password=password)
user.hash_password()
user.save()
```